# Different program arguments for 'run' and 'debug' in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, arguments

I want to have different program arguments for 'run' and 'debug' in Intellij Idea. So my program can slightly change its behaviour on handling logging and dealing with exceptions when I am debugging.

After searching for hours I have not found a solution for that yet.
Does anyone if this is possible in Intellij Idea? and if so, what must I change in my run configuration?

I know you can simply make two different run configurations one for 'run' and one for 'debug'. But this is just inconvenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible as of IntelliJ IDEA 14. Given that the JVM allows you to attach or detach a debugger to your process at any time, adding this feature would make fairly limited sense.